# Pandas filtering floating point to digit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean, pandas-groupby

I'm using Pandas to analyze my data. I have this dataframe consisting elapsed_seconds and m(magnitude). Is there a way for me to group-by the five digit of the float number(elapsed_seconds) and find the mean of m?

Example:

```
elapsed_seconds,m
10769.001,0.373637934043
10769.027,0.373403294813
10769.041,0.373069383556
10769.061,0.391354911476
10769.081,0.381280413801
```

What I need is :

```
elapsed_seconds,m
10769,0.3785491875378
```

0.3785491875378 is the mean of 0.373637934043,0.373403294813,0.373069383556,0.391354911476 and 0.381280413801

I will appreciate all feedback and comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert `float` column to `int` and then `groupby` and aggregate `mean`:

```
df = df.groupby(df['elapsed_seconds'].astype(int))['m'].mean().reset_index()
print (df)
   elapsed_seconds         m
0            10769  0.378549
```

Comment: Thank you sir @jezrael. Exactly what i need.